# Как правильно сказать: «заряд 18 кулонов» или «заряд 18 кулон»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные, выбор-варианта

Как правильно сказать: *этот конденсатор хранит заряд **18 кулонов*** или *этот конденсатор хранит заряд **18 кулон***?

Answer (score 2):

2. [**куло́н**](https://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/Kulon-62889%20(1).html), -а; *р. мн.* **-ов**, *счётн. ф.* **куло́н** (единица количества электричества).
   (Русское словесное ударение. — М.: ЭНАС. М.В. Зарва. 2001.)

Существительные, называющие единицы измерения (вольт, герц, ом, децибел, карат, люкс, парсек, сименс и др. — наименования мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на твердый согласный звук), обычно имеют в родительном падеже множественного числа две формы – с окончанием **-ов** и с нулевым окончанием.
Нулевое окончание используется в так называемой счётной форме единиц измерения, то есть при указании на конкретное количество, число чего-либо:

15 вольт, 16 ампер, 17 герц, **18 кулон**, 20 рентген и т. д.

[Родительный падеж множественного числа](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/773-223_roditelnyi_padezh_mnozhestvennogo_chisla.html)

**Дополнение**

Математики и физики (в научных текстах и задачах) чаще всего пишут "кулон".

*С каждой независимой вспышкой — с каждым ударом молнии, который вы видите, с небес низвергается **20—30 кулон** электричества. Интересно, сколько же времени тратит туча на восстановление этих **20—30 кулон**, уходящих с молнией?*
[Механизм распределения зарядов](http://sernam.ru/lect_f_phis5.php?id=70)

*Рассчитать число молний, необходимых для компенсации утечек заряда в атмосферу, если средний заряд, сообщаемый молнией, составляет **20 кулон.***
[Из задачи от В. Е. Фортова](https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/9025/)

[В. Е. Фо́ртов — физик (химическая физика, физика плазмы, термодинамика, теплофизика), академик Российской академии наук (1991). Президент РАН (2013 — 2017).]

Comment: Там дальше сказано, что у некоторых единиц измерения в счётной форме допустимы оба варианта. Кулон относится к этим единицам, хотя там и не указано явно (но в других источниках указано — см. [здесь](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.16), например). Рекомендуется отдавать предпочтение нулевому окончанию.